# Determinant of Triangular-like Matrix & getting stuck in Algorithmic Proofs / Inductive Proofs

Tags: algorithms, induction, determinant

**Find determinant of following matrix:**
A = $ \begin{pmatrix}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \cdots & a_{1,n-1} & a_{1,n} \\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & \cdots & a_{2,n-1} & 0 \\
\vdots  & \vdots  &   \ddots & \vdots & \vdots  \\
a_{n,1} & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0  
\end{pmatrix} $

**Attempt:**

*Lemma 1:* there's only 1 permutation for the given matrix A, for which $ detA \neq 0 $ and that is:

$\sigma$ = $ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & \cdots & n-1 & n \\
n & n-1 & \cdots & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{pmatrix} $

*Lemma 2:* for the given matrix $ A $ , $ sgn(\sigma) = (-1)^{ \frac{n}{2} (n+3)}  $

So, $ detA = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} sgn(\sigma)a_{1,\sigma(1)} \cdots a_{n,\sigma(n)} = sgn(\sigma) \prod_{k=1}^{n}a_{k,n-(k-1)} = (-1)^{ \frac{n}{2} (n+3)}  a_{1,n} a_{2,n-1} \cdots a_{n-1,2} a_{n,1}  $
and that's it.

**My attempt of Proof of lemma 1:**

Let $ \sigma \in S_n $ be arbitrary.
If $ \sigma(n) \neq 1 $ then $  a_{n,\sigma(n)} = 0  $ and then $
sgn(\sigma)a_{1,\sigma(1)} \cdots a_{n,\sigma(n)} = 0 $ .
Else if $ \sigma(n) = 1 $ then $ a_{n,\sigma(n)} = a_{n,1} $ .
It follows that $ \sigma(n-1) = 2 $ since otherwise, it can't be that  $ \sigma(n-1) = 1  (  \text{since  $ \sigma $ is one-to-one } ) $ and if $ \sigma(n-1) \neq  2, 1 $ , then clearly $ a_{n-1,\sigma(n-1)} = 0 $ and so  $ sgn(\sigma)a_{1,\sigma(1)} \cdots a_{n,\sigma(n)} = 0 $ .
Continuing in this fashion until we reach $ \sigma(1) $, we'll show for every $ k \in \mathbb{N} \text{ s.c. } k \leq n $ , that $ \sigma(k) = n-(k-1) $

**My attempt of Proof of lemma 2:**

$ |B| = sgn(\sigma) = \begin{vmatrix}
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 &1 \\ 
0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 &0 \\ 
 & & \vdots & & \\
0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 &0 \\ 
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 &0  \notag
\end{vmatrix} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{j+1}b_{1,j}|B_{1,j}| = (-1)^{n+1}|B_{1,j}| = \underset{\text{each time we'll expand the determinant} \\ \text{of the matrix in the multiplication } \\ \text{ by the first row until we reach } \\ \text{  a determinant of a matrix of size 1 }  } \cdots  = (-1)^{\sum_{k=1}^{n}n+2-k} = (-1)^{ \frac{n}{2} (n+3)}   $

**My difficulty :**
My attempt of proof of both lemma's 1 & 2 is sort of algorithmic ( for proof of  **lemma 1** I say " Continuing in this fashion untill we reach ...  " & for proof of **lemma 2** I say " each time ... until ... " ). At start I wanted to give a proof by induction for both these lemma's but I didn't know how to apply induction for them. Algorithmic proof felt the way to go but I feel there are some lacking steps, and that I need to prove more things, like:

**In proof of lemma 1, I essentially say:**

" for each iteration of k ( for each $ \sigma(k) $ ) we prove that $ \sigma(k) = n-(k-1) $  "

Was this incorrect? ( to say in each iteration we prove something for that specific iteration )
Am I supposed to do the proof in each iteration? If so how? ( I think induction could be used to prove lemma 1 but It was too difficult for me to even see how to do it in this case )

**In proof of lemma 2, I essentially say:**

$ |B| = sgn(\sigma) =  (-1)^{n+1}|B_{1,j}| = \cdots = (-1)^{ \frac{n}{2} (n+3)}   $

How do I actually prove that whatever happens in the " $ \cdots $ " leads me to $ (-1)^{ \frac{n}{2} (n+3)} $ ? I feel induction is needed on this but seems very hard to apply ( I think some sort of induction going down instead of up )

I felt here that the boundary between inductive and algorithmic proofs are not entirely clear, what's essentially the difference? ( I think inductive proof continues infinitely  whereas algorithmic proof continues finitely up to some number )